# Search for Objects in DSpace that holds a custom made meta data field, and that matches a date range

Tags: dspace

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKPUr.png) I've made a custom meta data field (date type), now I want to search for Objects in DSpace that holds the meta data field, and that matches a date range is that possible? I guess I would need a search filter for my custom made meta data. So I configured this field as a Discovery (SOLR) search filter

should it be enough to add the metadata field to the list below in config/spring/api/discovery.xml

```
>> >>         <property name="searchFilters">
>> >>             <list>
>> >>                 <ref bean="searchFilterTitle" />
>> >>                 <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
>> >>                 <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
>> >>                 <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
>> >>             </list>
>> >>         </property>
```

and also to configure it at the bottom of the file, where the other filters are configured

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L363

Now I have done all this but searching does not work. I have done mvn package in source and cd dspace/target/dspace4-0build ant update and then ./dspace index-discovery

I still can't get this to work, please do you have any advice?

Here is the content of my discovery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

    The contents of this file are subject to the license and copyright
    detailed in the LICENSE and NOTICE files at the root of the source
    tree and available online at

    http://www.dspace.org/license/

-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire-candidates="*Service,*DAO,javax.sql.DataSource">

    <context:annotation-config /> <!-- allows us to use spring annotations in beans -->

    <bean id="solrServiceResourceIndexPlugin" class="org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceResourceRestrictionPlugin" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="SolrServiceSpellIndexingPlugin" class="org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceSpellIndexingPlugin" scope="prototype"/>

    <alias name="solrServiceResourceIndexPlugin" alias="org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceResourceRestrictionPlugin"/>

    <!-- Additional indexing plugin to implement the browse system via SOLR -->
    <bean id="solrBrowseIndexer" scope="prototype"
          class="org.dspace.browse.SolrBrowseCreateDAO">
    </bean>

    <!--Bean that is used for mapping communities/collections to certain discovery configurations.-->
    <bean id="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfigurationService" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfigurationService">
        <property name="map">
            <map>
                <!--The map containing all the settings,
                    the key is used to refer to the page (the "site" or a community/collection handle)
                    the value-ref is a reference to an identifier of the DiscoveryConfiguration format
                    -->
                <!--The default entry, DO NOT REMOVE the system requires this-->
               <entry key="default" value-ref="defaultConfiguration" />

               <!--Use site to override the default configuration for the home page & default discovery page-->
               <entry key="site" value-ref="homepageConfiguration" />
               <!--<entry key="123456789/7621" value-ref="defaultConfiguration"/>-->
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="toIgnoreMetadataFields">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key><util:constant static-field="org.dspace.core.Constants.COMMUNITY"/></key>
                    <list>
                        <!--Introduction text-->
                        <!--<value>dc.description</value>-->
                        <!--Short description-->
                        <!--<value>dc.description.abstract</value>-->
                        <!--News-->
                        <!--<value>dc.description.tableofcontents</value>-->
                        <!--Copyright text-->
                        <value>dc.rights</value>
                        <!--Community name-->
                        <!--<value>dc.title</value>-->
                    </list>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key><util:constant static-field="org.dspace.core.Constants.COLLECTION"/></key>
                    <list>
                        <!--Introduction text-->
                        <!--<value>dc.description</value>-->
                        <!--Short description-->
                        <!--<value>dc.description.abstract</value>-->
                        <!--News-->
                        <!--<value>dc.description.tableofcontents</value>-->
                        <!--Copyright text-->
                        <value>dc.rights</value>
                        <!--Collection name-->
                        <!--<value>dc.title</value>-->
                    </list>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key><util:constant static-field="org.dspace.core.Constants.ITEM"/></key>
                    <list>
                        <value>dc.description.provenance</value>
                    </list>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--The default configuration settings for discovery-->
    <bean id="defaultConfiguration" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfiguration" scope="prototype">
        <!--Which sidebar facets are to be displayed-->
        <property name="sidebarFacets">
            <list>
                <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <!--The search filters which can be used on the discovery search page-->
        <property name="searchFilters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="searchFilterTitle" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <!--The sort filters for the discovery search-->
        <property name="searchSortConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySortConfiguration">
                <!--<property name="defaultSort" ref="sortDateIssued"/>-->
                <!--DefaultSortOrder can either be desc or asc (desc is default)-->
                <property name="defaultSortOrder" value="desc"/>
                <property name="sortFields">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="sortTitle" />
                        <ref bean="sortDateIssued" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!--Any default filter queries, these filter queries will be used for all queries done by discovery for this configuration-->
        <!--<property name="defaultFilterQueries">-->
            <!--<list>-->
                <!--Only find items-->
                <!--<value>search.resourcetype:2</value>-->
            <!--</list>-->
        <!--</property>-->
        <!--The configuration for the recent submissions-->
        <property name="recentSubmissionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryRecentSubmissionsConfiguration">
                <property name="metadataSortField" value="dc.date.accessioned" />
                <property name="type" value="date"/>
                <property name="max" value="20"/>
                <!-- If enabled the collection home page will not display metadata but show a pageable list of recent submissions -->
                <property name="useAsHomePage" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!--Default result per page  -->
        <property name="defaultRpp" value="10" />
        <property name="hitHighlightingConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryHitHighlightingConfiguration">
                <property name="metadataFields">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryHitHighlightFieldConfiguration">
                            <property name="field" value="dc.title"/>
                            <property name="snippets" value="5"/>
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryHitHighlightFieldConfiguration">
                            <property name="field" value="dc.contributor.author"/>
                            <property name="snippets" value="5"/>
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryHitHighlightFieldConfiguration">
                            <property name="field" value="dc.description.abstract"/>
                            <property name="maxSize" value="250"/>
                            <property name="snippets" value="2"/>
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryHitHighlightFieldConfiguration">
                            <property name="field" value="fulltext"/>
                            <property name="maxSize" value="250"/>
                            <property name="snippets" value="2"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="moreLikeThisConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryMoreLikeThisConfiguration">
                <!--When altering this list also alter the "xmlui.Discovery.RelatedItems.help" key as it describes
                the metadata fields below-->
                <property name="similarityMetadataFields">
                    <list>
                        <value>dc.title</value>
                        <value>dc.contributor.author</value>
                        <value>dc.creator</value>
                        <value>dc.subject</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <!--The minimum number of matching terms across the metadata fields above before an item is found as related -->
                <property name="minTermFrequency" value="5"/>
                <!--The maximum number of related items displayed-->
                <property name="max" value="3"/>
                <!--The minimum word length below which words will be ignored-->
                <property name="minWordLength" value="5"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- When true a "did you mean" example will be displayed, value can be true or false -->
        <property name="spellCheckEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>


    <!--The Homepage specific configuration settings for discovery-->
    <bean id="homepageConfiguration" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfiguration" scope="prototype">
        <!--Which sidebar facets are to be displayed (same as defaultConfiguration above)-->
        <property name="sidebarFacets">
            <list>
                <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <!--The search filters which can be used on the discovery search page (same as defaultConfiguration above)-->
        <property name="searchFilters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="searchFilterTitle" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
                <ref bean="searchFilter11slutdatum" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <!--The sort filters for the discovery search (same as defaultConfiguration above)-->
        <property name="searchSortConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySortConfiguration">
                <!--<property name="defaultSort" ref="sortDateIssued"/>-->
                <!--DefaultSortOrder can either be desc or asc (desc is default)-->
                <property name="defaultSortOrder" value="desc"/>
                <property name="sortFields">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="sortTitle" />
                        <ref bean="sortDateIssued" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Limit recent submissions on homepage to only 5 (default is 20) -->
        <property name="recentSubmissionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryRecentSubmissionsConfiguration">
                <property name="metadataSortField" value="dc.date.accessioned" />
                <property name="type" value="date"/>
                <property name="max" value="5"/>
                <property name="useAsHomePage" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--Search filter configuration beans-->
    <bean id="searchFilterTitle" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilter">
        <property name="indexFieldName" value="title"/>
        <property name="metadataFields">
            <list>
                <value>dc.title</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean id="searchFilter11slutdatum" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilter">
        <property name="indexFieldName" value="11slutdatum"/>
        <property name="metadataFields">
            <list>
                <value>dc.nordiska.11slutdatum</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchFilterAuthor" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilterFacet">
        <property name="indexFieldName" value="author"/>
        <property name="metadataFields">
            <list>
                <value>dc.contributor.author</value>
                <value>dc.creator</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="facetLimit" value="10"/>
        <property name="sortOrder" value="COUNT"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchFilterSubject" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.HierarchicalSidebarFacetConfiguration">
        <property name="indexFieldName" value="subject"/>
        <property name="metadataFields">
            <list>
                <value>dc.subject.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="facetLimit" value="10"/>
        <property name="sortOrder" value="COUNT"/>
        <property name="splitter" value="::"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchFilterIssued" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilterFacet">
        <property name="indexFieldName" value="dateIssued"/>
        <property name="metadataFields">
            <list>
                <value>dc.date.issued</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="type" value="date"/>
        <property name="sortOrder" value="VALUE"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Sort properties-->
    <bean id="sortTitle" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration">
        <property name="metadataField" value="dc.title"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sortDateIssued" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySortFieldConfiguration">
        <property name="metadataField" value="dc.date.issued"/>
        <property name="type" value="date"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are on the right track.

1. Define the new filter and assign it a unique id.
2. Add the new filter as a search filter and as a sidebar facet.
3. If your new filter is for a date field, be certain that your dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format.
4. Deploy your changes, restart DSpace
5. Re-index the repository to force the items to be re-indexed

If it is helpful, the following sample file illustrates several custom facets that we have configured: https://gist.github.com/terrywbrady/d31fc1bcb9567204470f

Comment: my dates are in the following format:

dc.nordiska.11slutdatum              2016/12/31              en_US

is that OK do you think? Or should the / be - ?

Comment: Try changing a few to YYYY-MM-DD and see if it presents them properly.

Comment: I tried changing one to YYYY-MM-DD but it still was not searchable

Comment: Did you run index-discovery -b to force the index to rebuild.  Is your new filter appearing in the advanced search filter?  Try building a custom facet on another existing field to see if that succeeds.

Comment: I ran the index-discovery -b, and then restarted tomcat, and my new filter is appearing in the advanced search filter, still does not work, I will try to build a custom facet on another existing field

Comment: Do I need to change the dspace.cfg file? According to this? https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Modify+search+fields

Comment: do you see anything wrong if you look at the screen shot above? (see first line in my text)

Comment: I took a look at your screen shot.  You can fix the language that appears in the advanced search drop down by editing your messages.xml file.  It sounds like you successfully created the filter.  Does the filter behave as expected when you enter a search?  If so, I would have expected the sidebar facet to appear with data.  My best recommendation would be to study the sample link I shared with you to see some sample custom facets.

Comment: My comment in the following thread might also be helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dspace-tech/facet$20collection$20community/dspace-tech/odZK7rXgqts/d5QYFkAFBwAJ

Comment: Hi! I have now included the content of my discovery.xml file, can you see if anything is wrong?

Comment: And what do you say about my question concerning dspace.cfg? Do I need to add anything there?

Comment: I see you have added the new filter to the filter list but not to the "sidebarFacets" list.  Question: is the facet working when you include the new field in an advanced search? The field that you referenced in dspace.cfg does not affect the discovery facets.

Comment: The facet is not working when I include it in an advanced search - that is excactly my problem!

Comment: Sorry, I was focused on the sidebar facet, not the filter.  Since this is a date field, look at the definition for dc.date.issued.  Note the following properties. <property name="type" value="date"/>
<property name="sortOrder" value="VALUE"/>

Comment: Ok, I will try and add that and see if it helps, thanks!

Comment: Do i need to run mvn package and ant update after doing the changes to the discovery.xml? Or should it be enough with reindex and restarting tomcat?

Comment: If you make the changes in your [dspace-src{ directory, always run both steps.

Comment: do I need to do any backup on files before doing that?

Comment: I have done the changes in usr/local/dspace/config/spring/api

Comment: Yes.  Backup changes to the install dir before running the ant task.  If you are making your changes in [dspace-install], then you do not need to run maven or ant.  You do need to restart tomcat for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Is usr/local/dspace/config/spring/api [dspace-src] or [dspace-install]?

Comment: Here is a summary of the dspace directory structure: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-OverviewofInstallOptions.  This conversation is straying away from the initial question.  Follow up questions that are not related to the discovery facet may be useful to send to the dspace-tech mailing list.

Comment: Still have not figured this out. And I am do my changes in the [dspace-install] so that should not be the problem

Comment: I did the mvn package and it seems that it works now :) thanks for all the help!

Comment: or maybe it does, but do you know how I can search for example for objects that have a date that is in between two dates? A date range.

Comment: Do you know if I can make the following search in DSpace: All objects that have a date metadata field where the date is larger than 2015-12-01 but less than 2016-12-31